# how to skip a function call based on the true or false of if statement?

Tags: python, function

can anyone tell me how to skip a function calling if a particular condition is true for example `if r[3]=='Device':` if this condition is true then the next function call must be skip, and if this condition is not true then the next function call must execute.the code will be like

the first function :

```
    def sei1(r):
        if r[4]=='Device':
            print(r[1],r[2],r[3])
            if r[7]=='Device':
                print(r[5],r[6])
            if r[7]=='list':
                print(r[5],r[6])
            if r[8]=='Device':
                print(r[5],r[6],r[7])
            if r[8]=='list':
                print(r[5],r[6],r[7])
      def se(r):
         if r[5]=='Device':
            print(r[1],r[2],r[3],r[4])
            if r[8]=='Device':
                print(r[6],r[7])
            if r[7]=='list':
                print(r[6],r[7])
            if r[8]=='Device':
                print(r[6],r[7],r[8])
            if r[8]=='list':
                print(r[6],r[7],r[8]) 
       sei1(r) 
       se(r)
```

This are the two functions and what i need is if r[4]=='Device' is true then next function call se(r) must not execute.

i am new at python every suggestions are appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Use `!=` to check if something is not equal.

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: `if r[3]=='Device':
     pass`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to simply check as follows :

```
if r[3]!='Device': # function_call is a function which will only execute when r[3] is not equal to 'Device'
    function_call()
```

OR

```
if r[3]=='Device':
    pass
else:
    function_call()
```

Answer (score 1):

By skip do you mean not executing it? In that case, the good ol' simple if should just work fine?

```
if r[3] != 'Device':
    func1()
    print('function is executed!')
else:
    print('function is NOT executed!')
```

Comment: yes by skip i mean not executing

Answer (score 0):

```
if r[3]=='Device':
    pass
else:
    function()
```